# PostgreSQL. Превышение таймаута

Tags: c#, postgresql

Пытаюсь создать БД и таблицы при нажатии кнопки.
Иногда запросы проходят.
Иногда пишет "A timeout has occurred".
Иногда пишет "ОШИБКА: 57014: выполнение оператора отменено из-за таймаута".
**Код C#:**

```
String connectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User={2};Password={3};", Server, Port, User, Pass);
NpgsqlConnection conn_new = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
conn_new.Open();

String DB = "CREATE DATABASE " + DBname + @"
WITH 
OWNER = postgres
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'Russian_Russia.1251'
LC_CTYPE = 'Russian_Russia.1251'
TABLESPACE = pg_default
CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;";
NpgsqlCommand command2 = new NpgsqlCommand(DB, conn_new);
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
richTextBox1.Text += "БД создана\n";
conn_new.Close();

connectionString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User={2};Password={3};Database={4};", Server, Port, User, Pass, DBname);
conn_new = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
conn_new.Open();
String T_1 = "CREATE TABLE public.defekt" +
"(" +
"    q1 integer NOT NULL," +
"    q2 text COLLATE pg_catalog.\"default\" NOT NULL," +
"    q3 text COLLATE pg_catalog.\"default\"," +
"    CONSTRAINT defekt_pkey PRIMARY KEY(q1, q2)" +
")";
command2 = new NpgsqlCommand(T_1, conn_new);
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
richTextBox1.Text += "Таблица_1 создана\n";
conn_new.Close();
```

`

**ОС:** Win7 Профессиональная SP1 x64
**PostgreSQL:** 9.3.24 x32, 9.6.8 x64
**.Net Framework** 2.0
**Среда разработки:** MS VS 2017
**Npgsql:** 2.1.0
На WinXp SP2  с .N F 2.0 и PGSQL 9.3.24 x32 работает нормально
На Win10 Pro  с .N F 2.0 и PGSQL 9.3 x64 работает нормально

Comment: Слушайте, так нельзя. `command2.ExecuteNonQuery();` вернет количество обработанных строк. После создания базы вы должны дождаться возвращения единицы из этого метода, а потом уже рапортовать об успехе в создании базы и пытаться создавать таблицы в ней.

Comment: а как это сделать?(